# add th to tr in thead of table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I add a new `<th>` to `<thead>` using jQuery

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
</table>
```

Comment: It helps if you showed that you put some effort into this and posted what you've tried already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
$("#table>thead>tr").append("<th>Second</th>");
```